# IE bug - content floats left

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why does a page floats left in IE6 and IE 7?

[buggy site](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=article&parent_id=1&menu_id=1)

Comment: It's not an IE bug, your page is in quirks mode because it doesn't validate. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.automatydrzwiowe.pl%2Ftrunk%2Findex.php%3Fevent%3Darticle%26parent_id%3D1%26menu_id%3D1&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around buggy older versions of IE, you can center it something like this:

```
body{
  text-align:center; /* for older browsers */
}

#main_container{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  text-align:left; /* this is important */
}
```

Comment: It works :) Thanks! But I suppose that in 960 grid system: { margin:0 auto; width:1000px; } are not necessary

Comment: rather than making a mild css hack to circumvent 'buggy' browser behviour, perhaps making the page itself valid HTML and not end up in Quirks mode is a better approach. I'm not saying this answer is wrong, the problem just lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

IE6+ supports the "auto" value on margin property. However, it requires to display the page in standards-compliance mode. Removing the redundant <pre> elements before the doctype will solve the entire problem, without need to use text-align.

Answer (score 0):

Your page [is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.automatydrzwiowe.pl%2Ftrunk%2Findex.php%3Fevent%3Darticle%26parent_id%3D1%26menu_id%3D1&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) HTML, so I’d recommend you to make it valid first / as well. Esp. the errors and `<pre>` tags before your doctype.

To your actual problem: IE does not interpret `margin(-left): auto` according to standard. To work around it do a `text-align:center` in the surrounding block element (`<body>` in your case) and `text-align` to your preference on the actual element (`.container_12` in your case) again.